# How to conditionally enter column markup based on ng-repeat table?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

What I'm trying to do is to conditionally change what is displayed within a td column block, based on some value of my ng-repeat's iterated object value. More specifically, if you look at the code below, what I want to do, is based on some value of data.col2val, I want to change what is displayed in column2 for that row.

I know that there is no such thing as a ng-if-else, but if there was, my code might look something like this:

```
<table class="table" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="data in dataStore">
        <tr>
            <td>{{data.col1val}}</td>
            <td ng-if="{{data.col2val}}='something'" style="somestyle">something</td>
            <td ng-if-else="{{data.col2val}}='somethingelse'" style="someotherstyle">somethingelse</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Maybe there is a trivial way to do this, but I can't seem to figure/google it out. I know how do to this what ASP.NET/Razor but not with Angular, so any assistance is appreciated and pardon my ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ng-if="data.col2val=='something'"
```

you don't have tu use curly braces inside ng-if directive

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){
  
  
  $scope.dataStore = [
    
    {col1val:"Mike", col2val:"something"},
     {col1val:"Mike", col2val:"somethingelse"},
    
  ];
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    
    <table class="table" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="data in dataStore">
        <tr>
            <td>{{data.col1val}}</td>
            <td ng-if="data.col2val=='something'" style="somestyle">something</td>
            <td ng-if="data.col2val=='somethingelse'" style="someotherstyle">somethingelse</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Both proposed solutions worked, but I had a syntax error in my comparison (duh!) - I was using '=' and not '==', which was corrected in this answer. Thanks!